# DotNetOpenAuth VS IdentityServer3

Tags: dotnetopenauth, identityserver3, identityserver4, identityserver2

What are the pro and cons of using DotNetOpenAuth vs IdnetityServer3/4 as the OAuth2 Authorization Server.

What is most popular choice among these two and why?

Comment: Did you ever gather enough information to form an opinion on this? I am facing a similar dilemma, and in my case, .NET Framework support (not .NET Core/5+) is a constraint.